# What kind of sensor is ideal for measuring the eccentricity of a threaded shaft?

Tags: materials

I am supposed to come up with an eccentricity measurement system for surfaces. What kind of sensor/configuration is most ideal for such an application(in the generic sense).

Comment: I think we probably need more detail to provide a meaningful answer. Things like what level of precision you care about, how many measurements you want to take, and so on. A system suitable for a machinist to center a shaft in lathe chuck to a precision of a thousandth of an inch is quite a bit different from a system to measure eccentricity of ten thousand parts per hour to sub-micron precision.

Comment: Are you looking at the threaded part or the shank? Dial gauges have rounded ends to deal with smooth (relatively) surfaces, but if you wanted to measure the "sharp" point of the thread to define the eccentricity then perhaps a roller may work.

Comment: Suppose you have an elliptical cross section shaft and it is bowed.  Do you care more about the cross section or how the bowed part swings through space as the shaft turns?

Comment: You mean like a plunger-type dial indicator? Or a CMM? That's not even mentioning the indexing head or indexing collet chuck which you will need to mount the part. Is this a student project? You will also need a reference shaft to calibrate and set up everything to be straight and centered.